# Web Application project ignores project-level imports

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Is anyone else seeing this problem?

I've created a new Web Application project (`net471`), and it's ignoring project-level import directives.

I can specify class-level directives just fine:

[image]

But when I remove the directive I get this:

[image]

Note that both of these screenshots were taken while this checkbox remained selected:

[image]

I'm considering reporting this as a bug, but I'd like to find out first whether others are seeing this as well and may have found a solution.

I don't get this behavior in other project types, e.g. Console App. I've tried it with the enum at both project root and in the `App_Code` special folder.

When I target a different Framework version, e.g. `net461`, the IDE briefly recognizes the `DescriptionAttribute` as would normally be expected, but then immediately falls back into error state.

I'm running VS 15.5.2.

Comment: I'll test your issue when I get the chance but I just wanted to ask why you have an `Enum` declared inside a `Module`. An `Enum` is a first-class type in its own right so there's no point to declaring it inside another type. If you wouldn't declare a class or a structure inside a module then there's no good reason to declare an enumeration that way either.

Comment: @jmcilhinney — Thanks for having a look. I do the `Module` bit as a matter of habit so that I can apply obfuscation attributes en mass to all of my `Enum`s. I should note, however, that moving the `Enum` outside the `Module` doesn't alleviate this problem. So it doesn't appear to be related. Also... other project-level `Imports` *do* work, e.g. `System.IO`. This is an odd one. Must be an IDE bug.